# how to change date format to just year and month but must stay as a date value not varchar, or char..?

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, format, date-conversion

I read other similar question where the answer is to use FORMAT(getdate(),'yyy-MM') or something similar. However the problem for me in using anything like this, is that it changes the date type to a varchar or char. **I need it to stay as datetype** but just want Year and Month.. I tried the following..-> **FORMAT(a.completeddate,'yyy-MM')** which works to change to year and month but the date is no longer a datetype or date format. So when I try to do the following -> **select @FirstCompletion =  (A.completeddate)** i get this error..**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.** Basically I need to convert the date column to year and month as date format so I can then pass values to variables using **select @FirstCompletion =  (A.completeddate) and set @secondMonth = DATEADD(month, 2, @FirstCompletion)** which are Datetype variables.. Would appreciate any help I can get.. Thanks..

Comment: MS SQL Server? Please tag your question with brand and the sql tag.

Comment: You can use the first day of the month as a representative of the whole month.